# How can I refactor this code having multiple if-else?

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, spring-data-jpa

I have a class with many "if else". I don't know how i can refactor it. I think about Factory Pattern, but i don't know how implement it. Anyone help me?

```
    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(@NotNull Root<E> root, @NotNull CriteriaQuery<?> cq, @NotNull CriteriaBuilder cb) {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        for (SearchCriteria criteria : criteriaList) {
            if (criteria.getValue() == null) {
                predicates.add(cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true)));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(GREATER_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get(criteria.getKey()).as(criteria.getKey().getClass()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(LESS_THAN)) {
                predicates.add(cb.lessThan(root.get(criteria.getKey()).as(criteria.getKey().getClass()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(GREATER_THAN_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(criteria.getKey()).as(criteria.getKey().getClass()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(LESS_THAN_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(criteria.getKey()).as(criteria.getKey().getClass()), criteria.getValue().toString()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(NOT_EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(cb.notEqual(root.get(criteria.getKey()).as(criteria.getKey().getClass()), criteria.getValue()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(EQUAL)) {
                predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()).as(criteria.getKey().getClass()), criteria.getValue()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(MATCH)) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(criteria.getKey())), "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(MATCH_END)) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(criteria.getKey())), criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase() + "%"));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(MATCH_START)) {
                predicates.add(cb.like(cb.lower(root.get(criteria.getKey())), "%" + criteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(IN)) {
                predicates.add(cb.in(root.get(criteria.getKey())).value(criteria.getValue()));
            } else if (criteria.getOperation().equals(NOT_IN)) {
                predicates.add(cb.not(root.get(criteria.getKey())).in(criteria.getValue()));
            }
        }
        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you could use a switch statement.

Comment: i would like to use a pattern.

Comment: You could add a method in operation objects that constructs a predicate so you end up doing something  like predicates.add(criteria.getOperation().createPredicate(root, criteria)), only special  case remaining would be your first if statement that tests for null.

Answer (score 0):

Write `SearchCriteria.java` interface, something like this:

```
public interface SearchCriteria {

    String getOperation();
}
```

Than write Criteria classes which will implement this interface, something like this :

```
public class LessThanCriteria implements SearchCriteria {

    public static final String LESS = "some value";

    @Override
    public String getOperation() {
        return LESS;
    }
}

public class GreatherThanCriteria implements SearchCriteria {

    public static final String GREATER_THAN = "some value";

    @Override
    public String getOperation() {
        return GREATER_THAN;
    }
}
```

ect.

Than write `PredicateFactory.java` class that encapsulates logic for creating predicate object based on SearchCriteria.

```
public class PredicateFactory {

    public static final String LESS = "some value";
    public static final String LESS_THAN_EQUAL = "some value";
    public static final String NOT_EQUAL = "some value";
    public static final String EQUAL = "some value";
    public static final String MATCH = "some value";
    public static final String MATCH_END = "some value";
    public static final String MATCH_START = "some value";
    public static final String IN = "some value";
    public static final String NOT_IN = "some value";

    public static Predicate getPredicate(SearchCriteria criteria){
        if(criteria == null){
            return null;
        }
        if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(LESS)){
            return new Predicate(); // here you create predicate object that 
                                          // you want, 
                                        //based on criteria

        } else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(LESS_THAN_EQUAL)){
            return new Predicate();

        } else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(NOT_EQUAL)){
            return new Predicate();
        }
        else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(EQUAL)){
             return new Predicate();
        }
        else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(MATCH)){
            return new Predicate();
        }
        else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(MATCH_END)){
            return new Predicate();
        }
        else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(MATCH_START)){
            return new Predicate();
        }
        else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(IN)){
            return new Predicate();
        }
        else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(NOT_IN)){
            return new Predicate();
        }
        return null;
    }
    
}
```

Finally, use this Factory class in foor loop :

```
for (SearchCriteria criteria : criteriaList) {
      Predicate p = PredicateFactory.getPredicate(criteria);
      predicates.add(p); 

}
```

Comment: @Henry You have logic of object creation encapsulated in one place, which is a factory class. If you need to add new criteria you can create new class that will implement SearchCriteria interface, and then add that condition in one place, inside factory class.

Answer (score 0):

[Factory Pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/factory-method) is a creational pattern. So, it's used for constructing an object and some common interface needs to exist between the various uses. This doesn't directly apply to your case for now.

Assume you can edit CriteriaBuilder, you can do the following:

1. (Optional) Replace `criteria.getOperation()`, `criteria.getKey()`, `criteria.value()` with local variables `op`, `key` and `value` to make the code more readable.
2. Update `CriteriaBuilder` to expose a single method like `build(root, key, value, op)` and move the code of how to build each criteria into this method.
3. In your `toPredicate()`, you can simply `predicates.add(cb.build(root, key, value, op))`.

You may argue that this approach only moves the giant if-else block into `cb.build()` method; however, this is one step closer to a cleaner code. `cb.build()` is essentially the factory method that you're looking for, and the caller (`toPredicate()`) doesn't have to know about the logic of building a criteria.

You can continue to improve the if-else logic into `cb.build()` as you have direct access to the private fields in `CriteriaBuilder`. It's hard to tell what's the next step without seeing to code of `CriteriaBuilder`.

Answer (score -1):

You can check this , find a good example that by Eugen Paraschiv

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(final Root<T> root, final CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder builder) {
    final List<Object> args = castArguments(root);
    final Object argument = args.get(0);
    switch (RsqlSearchOperation.getSimpleOperator(operator)) {

    case EQUAL: {
        if (argument instanceof String) {
            return builder.like(root.get(property), argument.toString().replace('*', '%'));
        } else if (argument == null) {
            return builder.isNull(root.get(property));
        } else {
            return builder.equal(root.get(property), argument);
        }
    }
    case NOT_EQUAL: {
        if (argument instanceof String) {
            return builder.notLike(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString().replace('*', '%'));
        } else if (argument == null) {
            return builder.isNotNull(root.get(property));
        } else {
            return builder.notEqual(root.get(property), argument);
        }
    }
    case GREATER_THAN: {
        return builder.greaterThan(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
    }
    case GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL: {
        return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
    }
    case LESS_THAN: {
        return builder.lessThan(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
    }
    case LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL: {
        return builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<String> get(property), argument.toString());
    }
    case IN:
        return root.get(property).in(args);
    case NOT_IN:
        return builder.not(root.get(property).in(args));
    }

    return null;
}

// === private

private List<Object> castArguments(final Root<T> root) {
    
    final Class<? extends Object> type = root.get(property).getJavaType();
    
    final List<Object> args = arguments.stream().map(arg -> {
        if (type.equals(Integer.class)) {
           return Integer.parseInt(arg);
        } else if (type.equals(Long.class)) {
           return Long.parseLong(arg);
        } else {
            return arg;
        }            
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return args;
}
```